# how to stopPropagation in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

My HTML code is like this:

```
<li data-id="<%=p.id %>" data-len="<%=products.length %>" data-count="<%=count %>">
    <div class="pro_list_imgbox">
        <img src="" />
    </div>
</li>
```

and my js code is like this:

```
events: {
            'click .pro_list_imgbox': 'loadPic',
            'click li[data-id]': 'detailHandler'
        },

loadPic: function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target),
                pic = target[0].nodeName === 'IMG' ? target : target.find('img');

            if (!pic.data('loadState')) {
                e.stopPropagation();
                if (e.isPropagationStopped()) {
                    alert('stoped');
                }
                pic.attr('src', pic[0].src += '?t' + new Date().getTime());
            }

        },

detailHandler: function (e) {
            alert('haha');
        },
```

I've invoked e.stopPropagation() in function loadPic when I click the img element and it's called successfully.
But why detailHandler still excuted and 'haha' alert.
How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried `stopImmediatePropagation` (not sure will help)? Though I do believe `stopPropagation` should work. 
Anyway could you plz make a http://jsfiddle.net/ demonstrating the issue?

Comment: Seems to work as expected http://jsfiddle.net/h6cLcs7h/

Comment: @Yury Tarabanko stopImmediatePropagation works perfectly,thx

Comment: @nikoshr my code is just a part of my project.maybe some other code lead to that problem,but I have another question: how can I render specific element with backbone.js or maybe do not need it?For example, after I click img element,I'm glad to see my pic reloaded.

Comment: This may be a stupid observation... Your `$.stopPropagation` function is inside an `if` statement.  Are you getting this error even when the code enters the `if` statement? Also, while most of us have no problem answering your second question in this post, StackOverflow, prefers that you open up a new Question.

Comment: I will open up a new question about my second question.Can u tell me what will happen if I put stopPropagation in an If statement?I'm pretty new in javascript.

Comment: If `$.stopPropagation` is inside your `if` statement, it will only stop the event bubbling if your go inside the `if` block. Otherwise, the even will not be stopped. That may be what you want. In the context of your question I was wondering if maybe your code wasn't getting into the `if` block. Are you using a debugger?

Comment: It's getting into the if statement successfully.I think maybe the reason is that click event attaching to body element in the implementation of backbone.js.So stopImmediatePropagation() can solve my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are almost in the right direction. Please check whether the following fix your problem:

```
events: {
            'click .pro_list_imgbox': 'loadPic',
            'click li[data-id]': 'detailHandler'
        },

loadPic: function (e) {
            var target = $(e.target),
                pic = target[0].nodeName === 'IMG' ? target : target.find('img');

            if (!pic.data('loadState')) {
                pic.attr('src', pic[0].src += '?t' + new Date().getTime());
            }
           //this return statement will not allow the event to propagate to the parent element.
            return false;

        },

detailHandler: function (e) {
            alert('haha');
        },
```

Comment: not work for me.Why could `return` statement prevent propagate to the parent element?

Comment: The event propagation is a serial process. When the previous callback for the child returns false the propagation got stopped. 
Checkout this jsFiddle example http://jsfiddle.net/1pssc6Lb/